# running transactions in db.Model subclassed put

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a google app engine data model with the following attributes:

1. store string, value pair into BigTable
2. if string, value pair DOES NOT exist, create the record
3. if string, value pair DOES exist, update the record, incrementing a counter

code:

```
class stringListRecord(db.Model):
    type  = db.StringProperty();
    value = db.StringProperty();
    refs  = db.IntegerProperty(default=1);

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        key = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM stringListRecord WHERE type = :1 AND value = :2", kw['type'], kw['value']).get();
        if key != None:
            kw['key'] = key;
        db.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kw);

    def increment_counter(self, key):
        obj = db.get(key);
        obj.refs += 1;
        db.Model.put(obj);

    def put(self):
        if self.key() != None:
            self.increment_counter(self.key());
            #db.run_in_transaction(self.increment_counter, self.key());
        else:
            db.Model.put(self);
```

When I run the commented out code, i.e. db.run_in_transaction() I get:

```
Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions.
```

Is there a better way to get this functionality out of GAE?

Comment: try: obj.put() instead of db.Model.put(obj)

Comment: protip: Python doesn't really needs semicolons

Comment: I had obj.put(), which gave the same error.  Semicolons are a hard habit to break. ;-)

Comment: You really shouldn't be subclassing put, or doing this in it anyway - write it as a class method. And you _definitely_ shouldn't be overriding `__init__` like that (or at all, preferably)! Also, your code is not safe against race conditions.